# Error: Quote strings required for name Teradata Fast load

Tags: teradata

I keep running into the error message on a Teradata fast load
 Error: Quote strings required for name

I have my script set to:

```
SET RECORD VARTEXT "|"QUOTE YES '"';
```

sample data set:

> "ITEM"|"DIMEN_TYPE"|"HGT"|"WID"|"LENT"|"WGHT"
>
> 123456|"D"|4.25|5.25|0.5|0.25

Any idea what I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure you need the word `delimiter` in there: `set record vartext delimiter "|" quote yes '"'`

Comment: I tried that and got the same error. The data comes from Oracle, I am not sure if that has something to do with the issue.

Comment: Try `QUOTE OPTIONAL` instead of `YES`.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the source data from a pipe to tab removed the quote portion

```
SET RECORD VARTEXT DELIMITER "  ";
```

and added

```
SET SESSION CHARSET “UTF8”;
```

This combination seemed to fix the issue.